# How does this type of static XAML Binding work?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I cam across the following code in a XAML document, and I do not understand the syntax, nor do I understand how it is supposed to work.

The XAML contains the following Binding (or I guess it's some sort of Binding):

```
<Button Content="Export all" Command="{atf:CommandService {x:Static MyProgramme:ExportCommands+Commands.ExportAll}}">
```

In this project, there is a class indeed called `CommandService` (which is quite large so I can't share the full code, but see [the ATF framework](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/master/Framework/Atf.Gui.WinForms/Applications/CommandService.cs)), and another class:

```
public class ExportCommands
{
    private enum Commands 
    {
        ExportAll
    }
}
```

I do no understand the syntax of the XAML expression. How does it relate the `CommandService` class to the actual command? Are there similar examples that use this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATF CommandService is a custom `MarkupExtension` provided by the framework. An example of a mark up extension can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf/)